# Radix Sort showing wrong values in the output

Tags: c, sorting, radix-sort

I am learning dsa and I tried to implement radix sort in c. I used this [tutorial from programiz.](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/radix-sort)
I implemented it but the array of numbers they are using get sorted correctly but when I used a different array it shows some garbage value.

When I insert this 
int array[] = {121, 432, 564, 23, 1, 45, 788}; 
The output is "1 23 45 121 432 564 788" [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmyaX.png)

 But When I insert this 
int array[] = {3,4,1,5,2}; 
The output is "1 2 3 4 2496"
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbU69.png)

I implemented the code as it is from the tutorial. Can any one point out the issue

```
#include <stdio.h>

void radix_sort(int array[], int size);
void counting_sort(int array[], int size, int place);

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {3,4,1,5,2};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    radix_sort(array, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void radix_sort(int array[], int size)
{
     int max = array[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
     {
         if (array[i] > max)
         max = array[i];
     }

for (int place = 1; max / place > 0; place *= 10)
    counting_sort(array, size, place);
}

void counting_sort(int array[], int size, int place)
{
    int output[size + 1];
    int max = (array[0] / place) % 10;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
         if (((array[i] / place) % 10) > max)
             max = array[i];
    }
    int count[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        count[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        count[(array[i] / place) % 10]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
       output[count[(array[i] / place) % 10] - 1] = array[i];
       count[(array[i] / place) % 10]--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       array[i] = output[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {` will access the array out of bounds since  `count[max+1]` => `count[5+1]` so your program has undefined behavior. It could crash or output garbage or do just about anything.

You should use `i <= max` in that loop:

```c
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)  // use `i <= max` here
    count[i] += count[i - 1];
```

You also need to zero out the memory of the variable length array `count` because it will contain indeterminate values after it's been created. You tried doing that with `for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) count[i] = 0;` but that misses the last element in the array. You need `i <= max` there too:

```
int count[max + 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) count[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Hey it did worked, Thank you soo much